# How to project a 3D point on a plane into a 2D coordinate system

Tags: 3d, projective-geometry, solid-geometry

When searching for 3D-projection you can find these diagrams, where the camera screens are always orthagonal to the x/y-axis.
[image]

But how do you calculate the 2D-coordinates when you have a rotation of the screen like so:

[image]

In this example all the coordinates (x,y,z) of the points C,A,M and B are given as well as (if needed) the equation of the camera screen

Comment: What do all the points and lines in your drawing represent?

Comment: C is for camera, A is the intersection of the red line and the screen, M is the middle of the screen and the blue lines are what im trying to calculate.

Comment: The 3-D intersection of $AB$ with the image plane is a simple calculation, but there’s still a big piece missing in order to complete the mapping into 2-D: you need to define a coordinate system for the image plane. Assuming that $M$ is to be the origin (if the visible region is limited you might want to use one of its corners instead), you still need to choose a direction and orientation for the coordinate axes.